# Angular 2 Animations in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, animation, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am making an ap with ionic 2 ANgular 2 and typescript and i needed to use Animations in it.
The problem is that the animation duration doesn't work, so the animation is instant.

**Animation Code**

```
animations: [
    trigger('slideInOut', [
      state('in', style({
        transform: 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)',
        "transition-duration": "300ms"
      })),
      state('out', style({
        transform: 'translate3d(100%, 0, 0)',
        "transition-duration": "300ms"
      })),
      transition('in => out', animate('800ms ease')),
      transition('out => in', animate('800ms ease'))
    ]),
  ]
```

**NOTE** : The transition-duration attribute was added by me in order to force the animation duration and it worked. So the animation duration is 300ms not the 800ms stated in the animate method.

The problem is that i know it is supposed to work without the added `transition-duration` but in my case it didn't, so what is the problem ?

**HTML Code**

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let Position of Positions"  [@slideInOut]="Position.out">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-avatar item-start>
        <img>
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2> {{Position.Name}}</h2>
      <button ion-button icon-only item-end clear large>
        <ion-icon name="checkbox" color="{{Position.voted==true?'secondary':'danger'}}" ></ion-icon>
      </button>
    ............
```

The `out` attribute is initially set to `"in"` then changed to `"out"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Do you have the `BrowserAnimationsModule` defined as an 'import' in your app-module.ts?

2) Are you using Safari/iOS. You may need [web-amimations.js](https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js) polyfill?

There's also a useful thread [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/angular-4-animations-not-working-in-ionic-3/90178/13).

Comment: I have NoopAnimationsModule in my app.module.ts
 and i am still using the browser to test

Comment: You might want to read this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362898/whats-the-difference-between-browseranimationsmodule-and-noopanimationsmodule Noop is used for testing

Comment: Thanks, that did it