# Angular 5 Animation - ease-in / ease-out time

Tags: animation, angular5

I am trying to do a simple transition using angular 5. The transition itself is working but when I try to adjust the ease-in / ease out period of the transition. My setup is based off of the [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/animations), so I am really at loss as to why the transition time isn't changing.

**component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('homeState', [

      state('hide', style({
        backgroundColor: '#eee',
        transform: 'translateX(0%)'
      })),
      state('show', style({
        backgroundColor: '#cfd8dc',
        transform: 'translateX(100%)'
      })),
      transition('show => hide', animate('6000ms ease-out')),
      transition('hide => show', animate('1000ms ease-in'))

    ])
  ]
})
```

**component.html**

```html
<h1 [@homeState]="stateName">{{title}}</h1>
<button (click)="toggle()"></button>
```

The toggle function changes between the show and hide states. Can someone please point me in the right direction? thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Okay, so I have done some more digging. I downloaded the source code of the animations. The source code has the easing effect working. So i copied that code over to my project and still the ease effect is not working. But when I copied my original code over to the animations project everything works.

```
Your global Angular CLI version (1.7.4) is greater than your local
version (1.6.5). The local Angular CLI version is used.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured it out. I had the noop testing module as well as the regular angular animations in my file (this is my fault, I copied someone else's setup without fully understanding what I was doing). The noop is a no operation module used solely for testing.

**more info:**
[What's the difference between BrowserAnimationsModule and NoopAnimationsModule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362898/whats-the-difference-between-browseranimationsmodule-and-noopanimationsmodule)

Once I removed this from my app.module.ts all was good:

import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

I hope this helps someone down the road.