# Why isn't my angular5.2 Animation not working

Tags: angular5

I have created an Angular animation for my application,Here is the code :

```
export const slideToRight = trigger('routerAnimate', [
  state('void', style({position: 'fixed', 'width': '100%', 'height': '70%'})),
  state('*', style({position: 'fixed', 'width': '100%', 'height': '70%'})),
  transition('void => *', [
    style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}),
    animate('5s ease-in', style({transform: 'translateX(0)'}))
  ]),

  transition('* => void', [
    style({transform: 'translateX(0)'}),
    animate('5s ease-out', style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}))
  ])
]);`
```

And i use HostBinding in my Component.ts like this

```
@HostBinding('@routerAnimate') state;
```

The code is too long, so it is not posted.
please look my gitHub[my application](https://github.com/zhangManGod/task.git)
why my animation's transition not working
thanks a lot

Comment: Please check https://github.com/zhangManGod/task/blob/master/task/src/app/app.module.ts
Line 28-29 u use both BrowserAnimationsModule and NoopAnimationsModule

remove import NoopAnimationsModule

refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362898/whats-the-difference-between-browseranimationsmodule-and-noopanimationsmodule

Comment: i remove import NoopAnimationsModule and it works.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Refer your source.. online 28-29: https://github.com/zhangManGod/task/blob/master/task/src/app/app.module.ts

In AppModule you import multiple animation module (BrowserAnimationsModule and NoopAnimationModule)

Try to remove NoopAnimationModule (use BrowserAnimationsModule only)

[What's the difference between BrowserAnimationsModule and NoopAnimationsModule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362898/whats-the-difference-between-browseranimationsmodule-and-noopanimationsmodule)